# Installing blender 2.7 on a command shell only linux (without X)

Tags: linux, 3d, debian, blender, blender-2.67

I tried to install blender 2.69 and 2.7 on my debian squeeze but it somehow requires X or another GUI. My aim is to run blender for blender scripting only. Means I have no use for the UI of blender or the installation of X or whatever.

It's mainly a performance issue, cause this machine is intended to do 3d calculations without any unncessary overhead.

I was able to install blender 2.49 via apt-get install, but I would prefer to get the latest stable version of blender installed.

Any one else faced this problem already and succeeded in this?

Any help or hints appreciated.

Cheers
kk3003

Comment: download the .deb directely from the pool and decompress it manualy, then try the func you need, if not working, look at dependency and try to solve some...

Answer (score 1):

The prebuilt versions of blender will all be compiled with X11 support, tools like apt-get will ensure that these dependencies are installed before allowing blender to be installed. But once blender is installed you can run it from a cli using the `-b` option which will prevent it loading the user interface and keep overheads to a minimum.

If you really want to remove the need to install X11 you will need to compile blender yourself and enable the WITH_HEADLESS option. [Start here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aDoc/Building_Blender/Linux) for details of compiling blender yourself.